# How to run codefight-2.2.2.0-zoosper in localserver

Tags: installation

i want to run codefight-2.2.2.0-zoosper in my localserver(localhost).

**Could someone help me in this case???**

I had studied the document and did accordingly, but when i open it in locally, it redirects me to http://nplab.codefight.org/

**THE INSTRUCTION I HAD FOLLOWED HAS GIVEN BELOW, BUT I'M NOT ABLE TO OPEN base_url   OR base_url/admin. PLEASE HELP ME...**

## Codefight CMS - a codeigniter open source php cms

### Steps to install:

1. Create a database.
2. Import SQL from old-install/files/codefight_latest.sql
3. Update app/config/database.php
4. Update app/config/config.php
5. Modify .htaccess as required.

### optional

1. Update define('CFWEBSITEID', 1); (if required) on index.php | no change required during installation.
   you can add more websites on same admin just use different website id on index file.

### admin:

base_url/admin

- user: test@test.com
- pass: test

### If you want to use same cms for 2nd website

just copy two root files (.htaccess and index.php) to 2nd website's folder, note, they should be on same server to share files.

Answer (score 0):

@ranjita updated code can be found here - https://github.com/dbashyal/Codefight-CMS

For redirection issue please check these files and settings:

1. check .htaccess
2. check app/config/config.php
3. you may need to update url in: http://yoururl.com/admin/setting/websites (if you can't access this url to update, check table `cf_websites`